# ANTLR4: Correctly matching common prefixes

Tags: antlr4

I have the following ANTLR4 grammar:

```
grammar test;

start_symbol: '(FILE' line* ')' EOF ;
line: '(' ID ')' ;
ID: [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;
White_space : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

... and it perfectly works on this sample input file:

```
(FILE
  (LINE)
)
```

But I also want it to work on:

```
(FILE
  (FILELINE)
)
```

This does not work. Obviously, the lexer generated an implicit '(FILE' token, which will also match the '(FILELINE' in the second line, which leads to an error.

How can I fix this?

Bonus: I also want to parse this:

```
(FILE
  (FILE)
)
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would do it:

```
start  : '(' FILE line* ')' EOF;
line   : '(' id ')';
id     : ID | FILE;

FILE  : 'FILE';
ID    : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
SPACE : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
```